# How to get data from object and assign in element in html - code by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, loops

I'm studying about getting data from Object by Javascript and I'm having struggle. I have an Object like that:

```
var people = {
  0: {
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "male",
    "job": "developer"
  },
  1: {
    "name": "Anna",
    "age": 22,
    "gender": "female",
    "job": "business"
  },
  2: {
    "name": "Jennifer",
    "age": 18,
    "gender": "female",
    "job": "student"
  }
}
```

I also have a html file like that:

```
<div id="people">
    <p id="name"></p>
    <p id="age"></p>
    <p id="gender"></p>
    <p id="job"></p>
</div>
```

How can I traverse my object to get the data and assign it to the corresponding p tags. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: "I'm having struggle" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML
`<div id="people"></div>`

then plain Javascript

```
for(person in people){
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    const name = document.createElement('p'); 
    name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(people[person].name));
    const age = document.createElement('p'); 
    age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(people[person].age));
    const gender = document.createElement('p'); 
    gender.appendChild(document.createTextNode(people[person].gender));
    const job = document.createElement('p'); 
    job.appendChild(document.createTextNode(people[person].job));

    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(age);
    container.appendChild(gender);
    container.appendChild(job);

    document.getElementById("people").appendChild(container);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For traversing an object you can use the [Objet.values method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). For the iteration itself you may use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). And to easily construct your string, you may use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Basic code on how this may look like:

```
let out = "";
for (let person of Object.values(people)) {
  out +=`
    <div class=people>
      <p class=name>${person.name}</p>
      <p class=age>${person.age}</p>
      <p class=gender>${person.gender}</p>
      <p class=job>${person.job}</p>
    </div>
  `;
}

document.write(out);
```

I also opted for the use of classes since ids should be unique.